# table in power apps You don’t have permission to view this data

Tags: powerapps, dataflow, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

i am tring to create table in power Apps it created successful but i cant use it or view data i got "You don’t have permission to view this data "

[image]

Comment: do you need a table or you need a collection? when you are creating table where are you creating it? In dataverse or sql or somewhere else?

Comment: Did you publish your customizations?

Comment: i created in Dataverse using SQL server , i can see data in Q Editor